# Gmod texture help

Tags: css

On my laptop, I wanted to play Garry mod  on Steam and I remembered I need CS:S textures for most servers and such. But, being on Ubuntu, I don't think that's the easiest process, so I'm wondering if anyone happens to know how/if I can apply those textures.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a common problem. I found [this](http://facepunch.com/showthread.php?t=1276199) on another site and it might be of some use to you.

Comment: You should add the solution itself to your question, and not just link to an external website.